# Error in NLTK file

Tags: python

I have installed Anaconda3-4.2.0 for Windows (64 bit) and nltk-3.2.1. While i am running the following code in Jupyter Notebook

```
`para = "Hello World. It's good to see you. Thanks for buying this book." 
import nltk.data tokenizer = nltk.data.load('tokenizers/punkt/PY3/english.pickle') tokenizer.tokenize(para)'
```

I am getting the following error:

```
'OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-a87e01558cc4> in <module>()
      1 para = "Hello World. It's good to see you. Thanks for buying this book."
      2 import nltk.data
----> 3 tokenizer = nltk.data.load('tokenizers/punkt/PY3/english.pickle')
      4 tokenizer.tokenize(para)

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\data.py in load(resource_url, format, cache, verbose, logic_parser, fstruct_reader, encoding)
    799 
    800     # Load the resource.
--> 801     opened_resource = _open(resource_url)
    802 
    803     if format == 'raw':

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\data.py in _open(resource_url)
    917 
    918     if protocol is None or protocol.lower() == 'nltk':
--> 919         return find(path_, path + ['']).open()
    920     elif protocol.lower() == 'file':
    921         # urllib might not use mode='rb', so handle this one ourselves:

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\data.py in find(resource_name, paths)
    607                         return GzipFileSystemPathPointer(p)
    608                     else:
--> 609                         return FileSystemPathPointer(p)
    610             else:
    611                 p = os.path.join(path_, url2pathname(zipfile))

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\compat.py in _decorator(*args, **kwargs)
    559     def _decorator(*args, **kwargs):
    560         args = (args[0], add_py3_data(args[1])) + args[2:]
--> 561         return init_func(*args, **kwargs)
    562     return wraps(init_func)(_decorator)
    563 

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\data.py in __init__(self, _path)
    298         _path = os.path.abspath(_path)
    299         if not os.path.exists(_path):
--> 300             raise IOError('No such file or directory: %r' % _path)
    301         self._path = _path
    302 

OSError: No such file or directory: 'C:\\nltk_data\\tokenizers\\punkt\\PY3\\PY3\\english.pickle'`
```

I have downloaded punktword tokenizer in nltk. Why I am seeing this error?Please give me an answer.

Answer (score 1):

It seems tokenizers/punkt/PY3/english.pickle file not exists. You need check it.

NLTK can download pickle file use download function:

```
import nltk
nltk.download()
```

Comment: tokenizers/punkt/PY3/english.pickle file is there. I downloaded Punkt Tokenizer Models from NLTK downloader. It is been installed in C:\nltk_data. Path is C:\nltk_data\tokenizers/punkt/PY3/english.pickle

Comment: Write the full path in your code, still have error?

Comment: When I gave the full path in code, it shows the following error:

Comment: I guess when NLTK detect ':', it will consider this path as an URL